# Combining multiple jenkins shared libraries

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to combine multiple shared Jenkins libraries?

E.g. I have a common shared library: **my-shared-library** (git repository with a maven project) defined on a jenkins folder that contains some jobs. Each 
job that runs inside that folder can use that shared library in the Jenkinsfile with:

```
@Library("my-shared-library") _
import com.pipelines.Pipeline
new Pipeline().build()
```

Now I would like to create another shared library: **my-specialized-shared-library** that contains a few specialized pipelines (in another git repository also as a maven project).
Pipelines (groovy classes, scripts etc) in **my-specialized-shared-library** should be able to use/import classes, pipelines etc from:
**my-shared-library** is that possible and if so what are the recommended approach?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on that? Also, it would be helpful if you posted the full code. Thank you.

Comment: The above is the full code. The Jenkinsfile only contains those 3 lines. The purpose is that I would like to "componentize" my shared libraries into separate git repositories/maven projects and then enable one to depend on the other.

Comment: In what way and why though?

Answer (score 9):

In Manage Jenkins > Configure System I defined 2 different Global Pipeline Libraries from different URLs.

- GlobalLibrary-1
- GlobalLibrary-2

The .jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('GlobalLibrary-1@some_branch') l1 //you can write here _ (underscore) or any other string.
@Library('GlobalLibrary-2@any_branch') l2
import com.lib1.Class1;  // import from GlobalLibrary-1 (Jenkins automatically finds com.lib.Class1 inside GlobalLibrary-1)
import com.prodcode.Class2;  // import from GlobalLibrary-2 (Jenkins automatically finds com.prodcode.Class2 inside GlobalLibrary-2)

node {
    new Class1();
    new Class2();
}
```

I can even use imports inside **Class2.groovy** to get classes from **GlobalLibrary-1**.

Comment: Found this on [Extending with Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/):

`/* Accessing multiple libraries with one statement */
@Library(['my-shared-library', 'otherlib@abc1234']) _`

Comment: Does this work when two or more libraries live in different repos (and also different projects(bitbucket) or orgs(github)  though? If yes, how would that be defined?

Comment: Yes @JohnZaj, it works with different repositories. When you define Global Pipeline Libraries in Configure System, you are asked to provide URLs. Each library has its own URL, no meter it is github, bitbucket or a path on your local drive.

Comment: I realize the question and answer are old, but this solution works from the Jenkinsfile perspective and forces you to KNOW the transitive dependencies of the library you want to use. Is there a way to define that dependency in the second library itself, and remove the need to explicitly define it in the Jenkinsfile (i.e. hide the implementation details of the transitive library)?