# Add additional stage to jenkinsfile along with importing jenkins-shared-libraries code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cobertura

Our project uses a jenkins-shared-library which has generic pipeline stages. We are looking at adding a stage that will inspect the code coverage and fail the pipeline if the coverage targets aren't met. The Cobertura plugin available with jenkins is capable of doing so, but I am facing challenges implementing it. Is there a way to add a custom pipeline stage in our jenkinsfile that will run after the shared-library code is run all as part of the same pipeline? Is it possible to import 2 shared libraries and use both together as part of the same pipeline? I am relatively new to this and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can import multiple shared libraries and use them as part of the same pipeline - you can also integrate your own stages as you described [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478705/combining-multiple-jenkins-shared-libraries)

Comment: @Bidisha does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for both your answers, they were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions : 
Is there a way to add away to add a custom pipeline stage in our jenkinsfile that will run after the shared-library code is run all as part of the same pipeline? 
Is it possible to import 2 shared libraries and use both together as part of the same pipeline ?
**Yes to both of the question**, you can add any number of custom stages in your pipeline and also it can run after the shared-library code is running. 
 Example of Jenkinsfile and new shared library file as below:

```
# stagelibrary variable will be used later to contain old_stagelibraries and is filled in # stage ('Old stage')
def oldstagelibrary

# newstagelibrary variable will contain path of your new sharedlibrary
def newstagelibrary
stage('Old stage') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Load Shared library Groovy file old_stagelibraries.Give your path of old_stagelibraries file which is created
                        oldstagelibrary = load 'C:\\Jenkins\\old_stagelibraries'
                        // Execute your function available in old_stagelibraries.groovy file.
                        oldstagelibrary.MyOld_library()       
                      }               
                  }
        }
# Add your new stage in the Jenkinsfile and use your new_stagelibraries file that is created
stage('New stage') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Load Shared library Groovy file new_stagelibraries which will contain your new functions.Give your path of new_stagelibraries file which is created
                        newstagelibrary = load 'C:\\Jenkins\\new_stagelibraries'
                        // Execute your function MyNew_library available in new_stagelibraries.groovy file.
                        newstagelibrary.MyNew_library()       
                      }               
                  }
        }
```

Create a file named : new_stagelibraries(groovy file)

```
#!groovy
// Write or add Functions(definations of stages) which will be called from your jenkins file
def MyNew_library()
 {
     echo "Function execution of MyNew_library"
     // You can add yoiur functionality here
 }

return this
```